# Problem with Linking an Image to a PDF file with <a>

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I am creating a website that displays a couple of book covers as images. The images display properly except when I put a tags around an img tag (because I want to link the image to a pdf of the book):

```
    <!-- Bookshelf -->
    <ul class='list-inline'>
      <li class='book'>
        <a href="./books/Things Fall Apart – Achebe.pdf" target="_blank">
            <img src='./img/bookshelf/things-fall-apart.jpg'>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li class='book'>
        <img src='./img/bookshelf/to-the-lighthouse.jpg'>
      </li>
```

[Picture of the distorted image next to a normal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWpro.png)

I'm not sure if this error is due to an html, css, or javascript problem, but I posted the github and website below: 
https://readcoloringbooks.netlify.com/ 
https://github.com/ShanRauf/ReadColoringBooks

Comment: Maybe the default styles for `a`nchor tags is giving you unexpected results. I cannot see the problem you have explain by looking at the image provided.

Comment: Me neither , I can't see the problem . Can you elaborate a bit more ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote an answer before and it was wrong sorry for that.
The solution is to replace all your

```
`<li class="book"></li>`
```

with

```
`<a class="book"></a>`
```

and at your file `css/library.css`
replace

```
.bookshelf li {
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
```

with

```
.bookshelf a {
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
}
```

and I'd recommend changing that

```
<ul class="list-inline"><ul>
```

with a `div`

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution is almost perfect. I had to set the display of the a tags to inline-block, because otherwise there was only one book per line showing. Otherwise, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot that, don't forget to up the answer  or mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

The Code worked fine for me. here is an example of how i would do it -

```html
<a href="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" target="_blank">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YCaGYUIfdy4/maxresdefault.jpg" />
</a>
```

It's best not to have spaces in your URLs, so either encode them or remove spaces in the file name, e.g. `/my title` to `/my%20title`

And ensure that the image you're loading is actually high resolution. Also, check to see if there is any CSS overriding content wrapped by `<a>`